# Error installing pscopg2

Tags: python-3.x, psycopg2

I have OS X Sierra and I'm trying to install psycopg2 version 2.6.2 within a virtual environment using virtualenv and Python 3.4. On the step "Running setup.py install for psycopg2" I get this error message:

```
ld: library not found for -lssl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that installing psycopg2 version 2.7.3.1 fixed the problem. So this bug must have been fixed in version 2.7 and above:

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/news.html